# How can I delete folder named C: inside the E:/ drive?

Tags: windows-8.1

Can anyone help me figure out how could I delete this folder named C: that was in a game folder. I tried deleting using FileShredder, and this created another series of folders that end up in a folder named C: that I cannot delete, acces or do anything with. I am using Windows 8.1

[image: screenshot of the parent folder]

Solved by using Chckdisk utility.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the folder is not read-only?

Comment: Your solution gets lost in the detail.  Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the folder is empty.
2. Open a command prompt with Start menu.
3. Type

> rmdir "e:\315687527292\3156875202581\3156875861048\315687531380\c:"

... and press enter.

(check those numbers, I don't know if I typed them correctly...)